# Sending audio signal to both back and front with Realtek USB Audio Devices

Tags: audio, drivers, asus, realtek-hd-audio, usb-audio

Old answers no longer apply. It appears to no longer be possible to simultaneously output the same audio stream to the front and back audio jacks when using new 'Realtek USB Audio' devices like the onboard Realtek ALC 4080 Codec, such as on the z790 ASUS Apex motherboard.

Are there any new solutions to allow this? That is, a single audio stream simultaneously sent to front and back outputs.

I have tested several solutions, using DriverStoreExplorer to do clean installs, repeatedly attempting different driver installs and trying to elucidate a meaningful and relevant response from ASUS Support. No luck.

There were similar posts on this in the past and great solutions which unfortunately no longer apply.

- Many years ago I could 'disable front panel jack detection' in Realtek HD Audio Manager, back with the ASUS Maximus XI I think. I attempted this with Realtek Audio Console, but it made no difference. I attempted to install Realtek HD Audio Manager, but after installation there is no Realtek HD Audio Manager (like it's a bare minimal install, and doesn't give the exe).
- With the ASUS Maximus XIII I had to use Realtek UAD Generic drivers and then use the Realtek HDA Driver Test tool to flick particular check boxes so that I could still simultaneously output audio. Sadly the Realtek UAD Generic drivers do not work with Realtek USB Devices (as informed by their primary contributor on github); the ALC 4080 is apparently quite different to the old audio codecs in how it is a USB device.

Your assistance is appreciated. First time posting here, apologies if I did something wrong.

Comment: Have a look at some of the stuff from https://www.vb-audio.com/ - I can't test, not on Windows, but this crops up frequently as the solution to Win routing issues.

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you. It looks like there are other modded drivers that I can look into which intentionally or not seem to have the effect I'm asking for, at least going by open issues in their githubs. https://github.com/AlanFinotty/AAFOptimusDCHAudio-Realtek